# How to override existing jquery ui datepicker properties to another

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two jquery datepickers.

```
<input type="text" id="DateOption1_Common" asp-for="DateOption1" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-br date-pick" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">

<div id="appointDP" class="datepicker" asp-for="@Model.AppointmentDate"></div>
```

Below is my script

```
if (Option >= 0) {

    var offDays = ($('#CalenderSettings').val()).split(',');
    var countryLocale = $("#countryLocale").val();
    $("#appointDP").datepicker(Object.assign(setLocaleDateFormat(countryLocale), {
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: selectedDate,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
    getSecondStepData(bookingOption, dateText);
    },
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [offDays.indexOf(datestring) == -1]
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, widget) {
    var date = month + '/1/' + year;
    getSecondStepData(bookingOption, date);
    }

    }));
}
else {

    var countryLocale = $("#countryLocale").val();
    $("#DateOption1_Common").datepicker();
    $("#DateOption1_Common").datepicker(Object.assign(setLocaleDateFormat(countryLocale), {
    minDate: dateToday,
    //changeMonth: true,
    //changeYear: true,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    $("#DateOption2_Common").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date()); 
    }
    }));
    $("#DateOption2_Common").datepicker();
    $("#DateOption2_Common").datepicker(Object.assign(setLocaleDateFormat(countryLocale), {
    minDate: dateToday,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    $("#DateOption2_Common").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date()); 
    }
    }));
}
```

Both datepickers have customized properties but when I select one then select second one. I'm not getting the second datepicker displayed as expected. How to achieve the expected result.

Comment: What are you expecting? And what are you actually getting?

Comment: @StephenMuecke second datepicker settings are overriden by first datepicker settings

Comment: I want first datepicker and second datepicker with custom properties

Comment: I'm quite confused .  1. There are three datepickers :  `#DateOption2_Common` , `#DateOption1_Common` and ` #appointDP` ? Which two are you dealing with ?  Could you please give us more information about your code ? 2. What do you mean by `Option>1` ?  3. Why did you call datepicker so many times ?  4.  Will the `setLocaleDateFormat` function make a deep copy ?

Comment: #appointDP and #DateOption2_Common